I am getting unknown layer error while testing a model
The error is this:
I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0.
2024-04-03 20:51:40.389067: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tf_keras\src\losses.py:2976: The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.
2024-04-03 20:51:47.709342: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\image caption\testing_caption_generator.py", line 68, in 
model = load_model(
ValueError: Unknown layer: 'NotEqual'. Please ensure you are using a keras.utils.custom_object_scope and that this object is included in the scope. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.
This is my code:
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
import pickle
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.layers import Lambda
from keras.applications.xception import Xception
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from pickle import load  # Import load function from pickle module
import tensorflow_hub as hub

# Define the custom layer
def NotEqual(x, y):
    import tensorflow as tf
    return tf.math.not_equal(x, y)

# Define functions for extracting features, generating descriptions, and other necessary utilities
def extract_features(filename, model):
    try:
        image = Image.open(filename)
    except:
        print("ERROR: Couldn't open image! Make sure the image path and extension are correct")
    image = image.resize((299,299))
    image = np.array(image)
    if image.shape[2] == 4: 
        image = image[..., :3]
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = image/127.5
    image = image - 1.0
    feature = model.predict(image)
    return feature

def word_for_id(integer, tokenizer):
    for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
        if index == integer:
            return word
    return None

def generate_desc(model, tokenizer, photo, max_length):
    in_text = 'start'
    for i in range(max_length):
        sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([in_text])[0]
        sequence = pad_sequences([sequence], maxlen=max_length)
        pred = model.predict([photo, sequence], verbose=0)
        pred = np.argmax(pred)
        word = word_for_id(pred, tokenizer)
        if word is None:
            break
        in_text += ' ' + word
        if word == 'end':
            break
    return in_text

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-i', '--image', required=True, help="Image Path")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
img_path = args['image']




#path = 'Flicker8k_Dataset/111537222_07e56d5a30.jpg'
max_length = 32
tokenizer = pickle.load(open("tokenizer.p","rb"))
path='models/model_9.h5'
model = load_model(
       (path),
       custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer}
)
xception_model = Xception(include_top=False, pooling="avg")

photo = extract_features(img_path, xception_model)
img = Image.open(img_path)

description = generate_desc(model, tokenizer, photo, max_length)
print("\n\n")
print(description)
plt.imshow(img)```


I think you can try adding this to register the custom function
model = load_model(
  (path),
  custom_objects={
    'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer, 
    'NotEqual': NotEqual, 
  }
)

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/serialization_and_saving#passing_custom_objects_to_load_model
p/s: the first line regarding TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS is just a warning message, it's not related to the error

ValueError: Only input tensors may be passed as positional arguments. The following argument value should be passed as a keyword argument: 0
code link: https://chat.openai.com/share/87ff3705-bc0b-435e-9262-285bd29ec4ce
